# one 1-form on the Riemann surface of an algebraic function

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Given the many-valued algebraic function $w =\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$,  we can get a Riemann surface  $S$ that is topologically equivalent to a torus. I am wondering whether the $1$-form
$ \displaystyle\frac{dz}{w}$ is a holomorphic form on the torus $S$.

On the surface we know that

$$ \frac{dz}{w}=\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}},$$

I think that $z=1,2,3$ are poles of the above 1-form, so it is a meromorphic 1-form on the $z-$plane. Is it a holomorphic 1-form on the torus $S$ determined by the algebraic function $w =\sqrt{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$?

I just know a little about Riemann surface theory. I will appreciate any suggestions and comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Riemann surface did you obtain? $C:w^2=(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)$ or $C-(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)$ or the projective closure $E\simeq C\cup (\infty,\infty)$?

Anyway $dz/w$ is holomorphic on them all: near $(1,0)$ we have $z=f(w)w^2$ with $f$ analytic at $0$. At $(\infty,\infty)$ we have $z=(z/w)^{-2} g(z/w),w=(z/w)^{-3} h(z/w)$ with $g,h$ analytic at $0$.

Eventually $dz/w$ is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic 1-form and $p\to \int_{p_0}^p dz/w$ is an isomorphism $E \to \Bbb{C/(uZ+vZ)}$ where $uZ+vZ$ is the lattice obtained by integrating over the closed-loops.

Comment: The Riemann surface I think is the first one, the torus $T$, which is obtained by Riemann's method from the algebraic function.  $T\subset \Bbb{ C^2\times C^2}$. I do not understand why $z=f(w)w^2.$

Comment: And why $f$ is analytic at 0?

Comment: What is $0$ ? The points on $C:w^2=(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)$ are pairs of complex numbers satisfying the equation. What do you mean with $T\subset \Bbb{ C^2\times C^2}$ ?

Comment: $F(z)= (z-1)(z-2)(z-3)$ is biholomorphic near $z=1$ thus $z=F^{-1}(w^2)=f(w)w^2$ with $f$  analytic at $0$. This holds only locally, and we'll have a different $f$ near $z=2$ and $z=3$.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Yes. It is $T\subset \Bbb{C\times C}.$

Comment: $w^2=(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)$ is not a complex torus, it is an (affine) elliptic curve, its projective closure is isomorphic to a complex torus ($\Bbb{C/(uZ+vZ)}$, the quotient of $\Bbb{C}$ by a lattice)

Comment: Yes.The algebraic function determines a  torus $T, \dim_\Bbb{R}(T)=2$.

Comment: If $z=F^{-1}(w^2)=f(w)w^2$, then $dz=[f'(w)w^2+2wf(w)]dw$. Hence we have $$ \frac{dz}{w}=[f'(w)w+2f(w)]dw$$ which is holomorphic  1-form.  But  how  can  $F^{-1}(w^2)=f(w)w^2$  be obtained? and why $f(w)$ is analytic at $w=0$?

Comment: No it is not a torus, it is an elliptic curve, but it is isomorphic to a torus.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean it from topologist's view.

Comment: And for it to be isomorphic to a torus, not a torus minus finitely many points, you need to consider the projective closure.

Comment: Yes. But I still do not understand the equation $F^{-1}(w^2)=f(w)w^2.$ Could you give me the details?

Answer (score 0):

Given the algebraic function $w^2=(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)$, differentiate each side, we get $$2wdw=[(z-2)(z-3)+(z-1)(z-3)+(z-1)(z-2)]dz .$$ Therefore we have $$\frac{dz}{w}=\frac{2dw}{(z-2)(z-3)+(z-1)(z-3)+(z-1)(z-2)}.$$ It is easy to see that the RHS is holomorphic locally at (1,0), (2,0),(3,0) respectively.